# Why are Raj and Howard referred to by last name in the early seasons (but not in the later seasons I think)?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

2 examples top of my head

S02E04

> Leonard: We’re here to see Koothrappali, not kill Batman.

S02E12

> Sheldon: Have faith, gentlemen. We don’t need Wolowitz, engineering is merely the slow younger brother of physics. Watch and learn. Do either of you know how to open the toolbox?

However, in both early and later seasons I believe they *address* each other by 1st name. It's just a few times when they *refer* to each other it's by last name.

Comment: They all work in an education environment, where this would not be at all unusual. There are people I went to school with whose first names I never knew; and even actual friends would be called by surname or nickname. First names [or more likely initials] were only ever used to differentiate two identical last names.

Comment: @Tetsujin well yeah but they don't do this anymore in the later seasons right? i'll edit to clarify thanks'

Comment: In the later seasons they became friends outside of academia and that might be the explanation for how they change what they call each other. Although I have a professor friend who calls his other professor friends by their last names often even when they have hung out consistently outside of work for decades.

Comment: @ToddWilcox 'In the later seasons they became friends outside of academia and that might be the explanation for how they change what they call each other. ' --> seriously? they were friends at the start i believe. even the flashback episode with how leonard met sheldon we see leonard already becoming friends with raj and howard...or something